# Bug with animation rate

Tags: graphics, animation

I tried to introduce an decay to the rotation of an object in mathematica by tying the animation rate to the degree of rotation as in the picture below and it goes quite smoothly until it reaches a little more than half then it starts spinning uncontrollably the animation rate becomes random. Does anyone know the cause of this bug and how to fix it? And if you know a way to make the animation rate decays please tell me how to do it too thanks.

EDIT: My code is

```
Animate[Graphics[Rotate[Rectangle[], x Degree]], {x, 0, 360},DefaultDuration -> 360/(360 - x)]
Animate[Graphics[Rotate[Rectangle[], x Degree]], {x, 0, 360}, AnimationRate -> 360 - x]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit your question to include the code you are running so it can be copied/pasted and reproduced.

Comment: Don't you think 360 is a too high value for `AnimationRate`?

Comment: @polfosol: `Animate[Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x], t Sin[x] + (1 - t) Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 
   10}], {t, 0, 1}, AnimationRate -> 360, AnimationRunning -> True]` works well.

Comment: The problem relates to changing `DefaultDuration` within the animation.  Adding `DefaultDuration -> 1/(1 - t)` to the final example in the `Animate` documentation produces the same problem.  Because the documentation does not warn about this, I view the problem as a bug.

Comment: By the way, `Animate[Graphics[Rotate[Rectangle[], x Degree]], {x, 0, 90}, 
 DefaultDuration -> 360/(360 - x)]` also produces the same problem.

Comment: @polfosol You can divide the animation rate by any value and it still has the same problem so I don't think the value being too high is the problem.